# Image width and height is not coming in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, file, filereader

I have to get the image width and height using jQuery ,but i stucked here.
Here image width and height is showing undefined ,please suggest me.
Thank you for any suggestion.

Below is **code**.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#file").change(function () {
      var files = this.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      var img = new Image();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        img.src = e.target.result;
        var fileSize = Math.round(files.size / 1024);///output is coming.
        alert("File size is " + fileSize + " kb");
        alert("width=" + this.width + " height=" + this.height);//showing undefined
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(files);
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="file" class="cropit-image-input hii" id="file" style="display: none;" >
```

Comment: Try `$(this).width()` and `$(this).height()`

Comment: @Jason its working ,but i have checked the width and height value ,its not the exact one .other image height and width are coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Checked in my desktop.

When I changed `this.width` & `this.height` to `img.width` & `img.height` respectively. It worked.

Change

```
alert("width=" + this.width + " height=" + this.height);//showing undefined
```

To

```
alert("width=" + img.width + " height=" + img.height);//showing undefined
```

Comment: Yup @Nana Partykar

Answer (score 2):

You can use `img` instead of `this`.

```
 alert("width=" + img.width + " height=" + img.height);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#file").change(function() {
    var files = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var img = new Image();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      img.src = e.target.result;
      var fileSize = Math.round(files.size / 1024); ///output is coming.
      alert("File size is " + fileSize + " kb");
 
      alert("width=" + img.width + " height=" + img.height); //showing undefined

    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(files);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" class="cropit-image-input hii" id="file">
```

Comment: @sradha, Updated answer with snippet